# Canvas JS - Circle animation that moves to center of screen when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, function, animation, canvas

I want to create a circle that moves slowly from the top of the page to the middle of the page when the page is loaded; however when I load the screen nothing appears.

I think the problem is with my move() function, but I'm not sure.

```
function move() {
    if (y == -75) {
        for (let i = y; i < (window.innerHeight / 2); i++) {
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            i += velocity;
            velocity += gravity;    
        }
    }
}
```

My CodePen:
https://codepen.io/michellevit/pen/jOrxOdE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `for` loop not doing what you would expect it to do. They are generally not the best candidates for this type of programming.

Instead use *recursive function* that checks every time what the state is and keeps calling itself until a certain condition is met.

```js
const myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let velocity = 0.1;
let gravity = 0.1;
let y = -75;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function move() {
  if (y <= (canvas.height / 2)) {
    y += velocity;
    velocity += gravity;
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  }
}

move();
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background: blue;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <section>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

It is another way of doing what you want to do

Comment: I think you forgot something.